# Why is Gorilla throwing an `unable to resolve symbol` error?

Tags: clojure, require

`:require` doesn't seem to be working in [Gorilla](http://gorilla-repl.org/start.html). I open up a new session and run the following:

```
(ns pacific-iceberg
  (:require [gorilla-plot.core :as plot]))

(defn f [x] (Math/pow x 2))
(plot f [-9 9])
```

Output:

```
An exception was caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException (Unable to resolve symbol: plot in this context)
...
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `:as` and `:refer`.  Clojure's `require` [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require) explains:

> Recognized options:
>
> **:as** takes a symbol as its argument and makes that symbol an alias to the
>     lib's namespace in the current namespace.
>
> **:refer** takes a list of symbols to refer from the namespace or the :all
>     keyword to bring in all public vars.

If you want a function from that library called "plot" you and you want to refer to it without name spacing it, use `:refer plot`, but if you want to make the name space explicit (my preference) then use something like `:as gorilla` then call it with `gorilla/plot`.

Comment: Ahh, right. I should have been using `(plot/plot f [-9 9])`. Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!